# Графическая оболочка на Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x

Возможно ли сделать графическую оболочку на Python 2.7 на чистом ядре linux? Если есть какая-нибудь умная книжка или статья, можете дать её.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.